# Wrap HTML Comments Within one HTML Comment in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I want to comment the whole section of DIV filled with HTML Comments with only one but i dont think its a possible in Dreamweaver...

I dont want to remove the existing HTML Comments but i want to comment the whole section for future use...

**Example:-**

```
<!-- Comments Starts -->
    <div class="post"> 
          <!-- Caption Starts -->
             <div class="title">Comments</div>
          <!-- Caption Ends -->
          <!-- Text Starts -->
             <div class="Content">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </div>
          <!-- Text Ends -->
    </div>
<!-- Comments Ends -->
```

Any Trick how to do it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My trick in .html file you can use `<script>/* ...  */</script>`

```
<script>/* 
<!-- Comments Starts -->
    <div class="post"> 
          <!-- Caption Starts -->
             <div class="title">Comments</div>
          <!-- Caption Ends -->
          <!-- Text Starts -->
             <div class="Content">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </div>
          <!-- Text Ends -->
    </div>
<!-- Comments Ends -->
*/</script>
```

If is a html with extension .php then use `<?/* ... */?>`

```
<?php /* 
<!-- Comments Starts -->
    <div class="post"> 
          <!-- Caption Starts -->
             <div class="title">Comments</div>
          <!-- Caption Ends -->
          <!-- Text Starts -->
             <div class="Content">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </div>
          <!-- Text Ends -->
    </div>
<!-- Comments Ends -->
*/?>
```

But i use it only for development work in progress and not for a finish website.

Comment: Well, this is a pretty nice and intelligent answer, thanks a lot of the solution